# Objects (ShapeRange) name VBA

Tags: vba, object, ms-word

Hi Guys I have a problem.

i'm working on multiple "*.docx" documents

they have similar properties and each of them have few objects (other docs)

The problem the particular object which i need to open has different name in different documents:

"Object 17", "Object 27" etc.

So im not able to automate it with this code:

```
With wd

 .Activedocument.Shapes("Object 17").Select

 .Selection.ShapeRange(1).OLEFormat.DoVerb VerbIndex:=wdOLEVerbPrimary

 .Selection.WholeStory

 .Selection.Copy

End With
```

THe point is that in every document this object has the same "name" ex. "**ASF_Debtor**" but from the code level it's "Object 17", "Object 28" etc.

Can is find somehow my proper object?

Comment: Did you tried using another property than object name? (Type, Size, Location)

Comment: Have you tried access it by `Shapes("ASF_Debtor")`? I just tested like this: I insert a textbox, the original name is `"Text Box 1"`. I then rename it as `"Test"`. Now `Shapes("Text Box 1")` and `Shapes("Test")` could access the same object.

Comment: yes i've tried there is an error: "The item with the specified name wasn't found"

Comment: What if you calling `Shapes("Object 17").Name`? If it returns **ASF_Debtor**, then you can loop thru `shapes` collection to check their names to find the specific one.

Comment: it doesnt work but i noticed that, there is something like "IconLabel" where is "ASF_Debtor" name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works now:

```
Dim obj as shape

For Each obj In ActiveDocument.Shapes

ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(i).Select


Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange.Name

Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange(1).OLEFormat.IconLabel


If Selection.ShapeRange(1).OLEFormat.IconLabel = "ASF_DebtorID" Then

   Selection.ShapeRange(1).OLEFormat.DoVerb VerbIndex:=wdOLEVerbPrimary

   Selection.WholeStory

   Selection.Copy

end if

i = i + 1

next
```